# Why the whole trigger is not running for the 200 records

Tags: apex, trigger, update

I have written a trigger In which I created a field Sequence Number on Contact to maintain its state in the update case but after after inserting more than 200 records for two accounts contacts then it does not maintain order of sequence number.
But it is working for fine for single Account.

```
 public void beforeUpdate(List<Contact> conNewTrigger, List<Contact> tempOldList){  
    System.debug('the size is '  + conNewTrigger.size());
    if(isFirstTime){    
        newConsIdsSet = new Set<Id>();
        conAcctsIdSet = new Set<Id>();
        for(Contact c : conNewTrigger){
            conAcctsIdSet.add(c.AccountId);
        }
        
        if(!conAcctsIdSet.isEmpty()){
            conWithAcctsList = [Select Id, (Select Id,AccountId,Sequence_Number__c from Contacts Order By Sequence_Number__c,CreatedDate) from Account where id in :conAcctsIdSet];
            //  Account oldacc = [Select Id,(Select Id,AccountId,Sequence_Number__C from Contacts Order By Sequence_Number__c ASC) from Account Where Id IN :oldAcctIdSet ];
            for(Account accts : conWithAcctsList){
                conMap = new Map<Integer,Contact>();
                conWithList = new List<Contact>();
                oldConMap = new Map<Id,Integer>();
                List<Contact> newtriggerList = new List<Contact>();
                Set<Id> oldAcctIdSet = new Set<Id>();
                System.debug('Account LOOOOOPPPPPP' + accts.id);
                /*Store the new coming recordsList into the newTriggerList for the particular at a time*/
                for(Contact c : conNewTrigger){//Filling the newTriggerList with the filtered records for particular account
                    if(c.AccountId == accts.id){
                        newtriggerList.add(c);
                        newConsIdsSet.add(c.id);
                    }
                }
                for(Contact cc : accts.contacts){
                    oldConMap.put(cc.id,(Integer)cc.sequence_number__c);
                    conMap.put((Integer)cc.Sequence_Number__c,cc);
                } 
                updateRecords(newtriggerList,conMap,oldConMap);
                isFirstTime = false;
                if(!tempList.isEmpty()) update tempList;
            }  
          
        }
    }
}

/*==================================== UPDATE RECORDS METHOD TO UPDATE ALL EXISTING RECORD AS PER THE UPDATED RECORDS ==========================*/
public void updateRecords(List<Contact> conWithList,Map<Integer,Contact> conMap,Map<Id,Integer> oldConMap){  
    System.debug('Inside the sdfasfd');
    Set<Id> idsOfNewContacts = new Set<Id>();
    for(Contact c : conWithList){
        idsOfNewContacts.add(c.id);
        System.debug('******************************************************');
        for(Contact yc : conmap.values()){
            System.debug('Initial the  : ----' +  '-----' +  yc.id +'---------------'+ yc.Sequence_Number__c);
        }
        Integer updatedSeqNo = (Integer)c.Sequence_Number__c;
        Integer oldSeqNo = oldConMap.get(c.id);
        if(conMap.containskey(updatedSeqNo)){
            if(updatedSeqNo > oldSeqNo && updatedSeqNo <= conMap.size()){
                for(Integer i = oldSeqNo;i<updatedSeqNo;i++){
                    System.debug('the seq no is ' + conMap.get(i).sequence_Number__C + 'AND con is ' + conMap.get(i).id);
                    conMap.get(i+1).sequence_number__C = i;
                    conMap.put(i,conMap.get(i+1));
                }
                conMap.put(updatedSeqNo,c);
                for(contact keys : conMap.values()){
                    oldConMap.put(keys.id,(Integer)keys.Sequence_Number__c);
                }
            }
            if(updatedSeqNo <= oldSeqNo && updatedSeqNo > 0){
                for(Integer i = oldSeqNo;i > updatedSeqNo;i--){
                    conMap.get(i-1).sequence_number__C = i;
                    conMap.put(i,conMap.get(i-1));
                }
                conMap.put(updatedSeqNo,c);
                for(contact keys : conMap.values()){
                    oldConMap.put(keys.id,(Integer)keys.Sequence_Number__c);
                }
            }      
        }
        else{
            /**NULL NEGATIVE ZERO OUTOFBOUND CASE**/
            for(Integer i = oldSeqNo;i<conMap.size();i++){
                conMap.get(i+1).Sequence_Number__c = i;
                conMap.put(i,conMap.get(i+1));
            }
            c.sequence_number__C = conMap.size();
            conMap.put(conMap.size(),c);
            for(contact keys : conMap.values()){
                oldConMap.put(keys.id,(Integer)keys.Sequence_Number__c);
            }
            
        }      
    }
    /*Separate the new values from the old values from the conMap by using old's Ids*/
    for(Id id : idsOfNewContacts){
        System.debug('The nEw ids are :: ' + id + '-----Final Id is ' +oldConMap.get(id) );
        conMap.remove(oldConMap.get(id));
    }
    tempList.addAll(conMap.values());
    List<Contact> temp = new List<Contact>();
    for(Id id : oldConMap.keySet()){
        System.debug('///////' + 'IDDD --- ' + Id + '=========' + oldConMap.get(id)) ;
        System.debug('^^^^>>>>>' + conMap.get(oldConMap.get(id)));
        temp.add(conMap.get(oldConMap.get(id)));
    }
    for(Contact yc : conmap.values()){
        System.debug('Final map tio be update the id is  : ----' + yc.id +'--------'+ yc.Sequence_Number__c);
    }
    
    
}
```

DML is like::

```
List<Contact> con = new List<Contact>();
  for(Integer i = 1;i<=101;i++){
    con.add(new Contact(LastName = 'k' + i,AccountId = '0015j00000WjZJd'));
    con.add(new Contact(LastName = 'l' + i,AccountId = '0015j00000WjZVP'));
  }
insert con;
```

And Sequence is like::

```
c1     5
c2     4
c2     3
c4     2
.      .
.      .     
.
cn     1

For Account 2:

t1   1
t2   1
t3   1
t4   2
t5   3
.
.
```

Comment: what does `isFirstTime` do - is this a trigger recursion variable?  I'll bet that your code also fails if you add 201 Contacts to a single Account (fails for contact #201)

Comment: I will check that Now can you tell me what is the solution for this Yes isfirstTime is recursion variable

Comment: Yes, It is also throwing same bug for records more than 200 how to fix this any Idea?

Comment: static boolean for recursion is not best practice; you need to use static Set<Id> for recursion control when you deal with > 200 recs

Comment: Okay! I m trying that

Comment: How can I use that